# Regex - Match string and certain suffix

Tags: regex

I have looked at some example but I can't get my regex to work correctly.  I would like to match when there is no suffix or the suffix is in a list.

Sample Data

```
Tom
Tom (2)
Tom (3)
Tom (4)
```

I would like to match everything but the Tom (4) row.  Each entry is on it's own line.  Can you point me in the right direction?  I can't seem to get my head around regex stuff.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `there is no suffix or the suffix is in a list`. Can you clarify?

Comment: Does that mean that only 2 and 3 are valid? Or only 4 is not valid and the rest from 0-9 is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

`Tom($| \((2|3)\))`

This would match `Tom` only, or `Tom` followed by parens with a `2` or `3`.

The `$` is an anchor to match the end of the line.
The `(2|3)` matches either a `2` or `3`.

Comment: `[23]` performs better than `2|3`

Comment: @ctwheels: I'm assuming "2" and "3" aren't literally what he's searching for. I think it represents "possible text 2" and "possible text 3".

Comment: Sorry, looks like my notifications weren't working.  This is exactly what I needed.  I couldn't get the OR syntax correct.  Thanks

Comment: @matt6288: don't forget to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted with a check. Glad I could help.